# How to describe the motion of a mass point?

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

Consider a mass point moving around a fixed point on a circle with radius $r$ with constant angular velocity $ω$. At a certain moment of time, the connection is removed, and the point mass is flying away tangentially to the circle.

I need to describe this motion in the inertial system (where the point mass is rotating in the beginning) and in a reference system rotating with angular velocity $ω$ around the fixed point (where the point mass is at rest in the beginning). How to do that?

Comment: Posting in physics SE would help you better.

Comment: Do you mean, how to describe a straight-line trajectory with $\omega$ and $r$?

Comment: @NotStrang I know how to describe angular velocity: $$\omega=\dfrac{\overrightarrow{v}}{r}$$

But I don't know how to represent the motion of a the mass point from the beginning and after the connection is removed.